# How to make \textsc look good in a section title in ACM documents?

Tags: fonts, sectioning, acm

**Q**: How can I suitably use `\textsc` in a section title in ACM documents?

I'm wanting to use `\textsc` in a section title in an ACM document, but it looks poor.  Here's a "Lorem ipsum" version:

[image: screenshot]

If I attempt to fix it using `\textbf{\textsc{...}}` or `\textsc{\textbf{...}}` it still doesn't look particularly appealing, and even gets rid of the small caps in subsections:

[image: screenshot]

The .cls file is available [here](http://www.sigmod.org/sigmod-pods-conferences/mirrors/sigmod2006/camera/acm_proc_article-sp.cls/view), and here's my LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem \textsc{ipsum}}

\subsection{Lorem ipsum \textsc{dolor} sit \textsc{Amet}}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas congue nisi justo, sed volutpat est convallis a. Aenean ultrices sed est quis tempor. Pellentesque eget iaculis risus. Nullam et lacus a justo interdum interdum at in neque. Phasellus eget lectus vitae purus posuere pellentesque. Phasellus ut fringilla lectus. Fusce maximus leo accumsan lorem posuere tempus. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: you need a font set that has bold small caps try `\usepackage{lmodern}` but if you are using that class for submitting to a journal, it doesn't make any difference, they'll use their own fonts anyway.

Comment: You can't; the ACM classes use a very nonstandard way to define fonts for section titles, which doesn't honor the standard font selection commands of LaTeX. Complain to ACM.

Comment: By the way, the fonts used by ACM for the section titles has no small caps (it's `mathptmx`, essentially).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Latin Modern doesn't have bold small caps....

Comment: @cfr ah. One of the extended cm does is it cm super? anyway seems like they want a times clone anyway....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes. `cm-super`. I never knew that. But, as you say, since they want a times clone and since the conference won't let them do this anyway in all probability, the point has little practical application ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how the class defines the fonts for the various parts of the document:

```
\newfont{\secfnt}{ptmb8t at 12pt}
\newfont{\secit}{ptmbi8t at 12pt}    %13 Jan 00 gkmt
\newfont{\subsecfnt}{ptmri8t at 11pt}
\newfont{\subsecit}{ptmbi8t at 11pt}  % 
\newfont{\ttlfnt}{phvb8t at 18pt}
\newfont{\ttlit}{phvbo8t at 18pt}    % GM 2/4/2000
\newfont{\subttlfnt}{phvr8t at 14pt}
\newfont{\subttlit}{phvro8t at 14pt} % GM 2/4/2000
\newfont{\subttlbf}{phvb8t at 14pt}  % 13 Jan 00 gkmt
\newfont{\aufnt}{phvr8t at 12pt}
\newfont{\auit}{phvro8t at 12pt}     % GM 2/4/2000
\newfont{\affaddr}{phvr8t at 10pt}
\newfont{\affaddrit}{phvro8t at 10pt} % GM 2/4/2000
\newfont{\eaddfnt}{phvr8t at 12pt}
\newfont{\ixpt}{ptmr8t at 9pt}
\newfont{\confname}{ptmri8t at 8pt}
\newfont{\crnotice}{ptmr8t at 8pt}
\newfont{\ninept}{ptmr8t at 9pt}
```

This is so wrong that I apologize for showing this code in a place accessible also to young or sensitive audience. `;-)`

You *could* fix this shameful code:

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}

\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage[scale=.9]{tgheros}

\renewcommand{\secfnt}{\bfseries\large}
\renewcommand{\secit}{\bfseries\itshape\large}
\renewcommand{\subsecfnt}{\itshape\large}
\renewcommand{\subsecit}{\bfseries\itshape\large}
\renewcommand{\ttlfnt}{\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE}
\renewcommand{\ttlit}{\sffamily\bfseries\slshape\LARGE}
\renewcommand{\subttlfnt}{\sffamily\Large}
\renewcommand{\subttlit}{\sffamily\slshape\Large}
\renewcommand{\subttlbf}{\sffamily\bfseries\Large}
\renewcommand{\aufnt}{\sffamily\large}
\renewcommand{\auit}{\sffamily\slshape\large}
\renewcommand{\affaddr}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\affaddrit}{\sffamily\slshape}
\renewcommand{\eaddfnt}{\sffamily\large}
\renewcommand{\ixpt}{\small}
\renewcommand{\confname}{\itshape\scriptsize}
\renewcommand{\crnotice}{\scriptsize}
\renewcommand{\ninept}{\small}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem \textsc{ipsum}}

\subsection{Lorem ipsum \textsc{dolor} sit \textsc{Amet}}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas congue nisi justo, sed 
volutpat est convallis a. Aenean ultrices sed est quis tempor. Pellentesque eget iaculis 
risus. Nullam et lacus a justo interdum interdum at in neque. Phasellus eget lectus vitae 
purus posuere pellentesque. Phasellus ut fringilla lectus. Fusce maximus leo accumsan lorem 
posuere tempus.

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I don't think that the people in charge of receiving manuscripts for the conference will be happy with this.